# Java 8 - apparent inconsistency between anonymous classes and lambda functions

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, anonymous-class, functional-interface

while investigating around with Java 8 functional programming, I found the following apparent inconsistency. The two constructs here below should be equivalent:

```
  public static BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> addTwoIntegers (Integer i1, Integer i2)
  {
    return new BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>()
    {
      @Override
      public Integer apply(Integer i1, Integer i2)
      {
        return i1 +i2;
      }
    };
  }

  public static BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> addTwoIntegers2 (Integer i1, Integer i2)
  {
    return (i1x, i2x) -> i1 + i2;
  }
```

The first declaration is a traditional anonymous class while the second one is a lambda function, but otherwise they should be equivalent. Now, calling them as follows:

```
    System.out.println("addTwoIntegers: " + addTwoIntegers(new Integer(0), new Integer(0)).apply(new Integer(5), new Integer(7)));
    System.out.println("addTwoIntegers2: " + addTwoIntegers2(new Integer(0), new Integer(0)).apply(new Integer(5), new Integer(7)));
```

I get:

```
addTwoIntegers: 12
addTwoIntegers2: 0
```

So either the two declaration aren't equivalent, which is hard to admit, or, if they are equivalent, given that they are callede in the same context, with the same parameters, they should produce the same result. Isn't it an inconsistency ?
Many thanks in advance to whoever can shade some light here.
Kind regards, Nicolas

Comment: This looks like it's caused by shadowing of parameters. In the first case, the inner method has the same parameter names as the outer, which isn't the case in the lambda. Is this intentional? This causes the lambda to use the first values given to it, while the anon class is using the second set.

Comment: No, it is not. It's just the the following:
      public static BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> addTwoIntegers2 (Integer i1, Integer i2)
      {
        return (i1, i2) -> i1 + i2;
      }
doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

The declarations are not equivalent. Due to [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the first method can be translated to function as:

```
public static BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> addTwoIntegers(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
    return (i1x, i2x) -> i1x + i2x;
}
```

The second method function expression refers to `addTwoIntegers2` method parameters `i1` and `i2` instead of the function parameters `i1x` and `i2x`. `i1` are `i2` available in the function closure, since they are both `0` the result is `0`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, this explains, thanks. But is there any way to avoid writing addTwoIntegers2(new Integer(0), new Integer(0)).apply(new Integer(5), new Integer(7)), i.e. to assign values twice to the parameters ?

Comment: @Nicolas both methods make little sense, since they ignore the first pair of argument. The code should be `BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> addTwoIntegers()` without any parameters.

Comment: okay, so it should be like:
`code`  public static BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> addTwoIntegers ()
  {
    return new BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>()
    {
      @Override
      public Integer apply(Integer i1, Integer i2)
      {
        return i1 +i2;
      }
    };
  }

  public static BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> addTwoIntegers2 ()
  {
    return (i1x, i2x) -> i1x + i2x;
  }
`code`
right ?

Answer (score 1):

> So either the two declaration aren't equivalent, which is hard to
> admit,

#### They are indeed not equivalent!

The method arguments for `addTwoIntegers` i.e. `i1` and `i2` **are unused** in your first sample.

```
public static BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> addTwoIntegers(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
    // to aid to debugging
    System.out.println(String.format("In addTwoIntegers i1: %s, i2: %s", i1, i2)); 
    return new BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer apply(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
            // see the difference in value as you run
            System.out.println(String.format("In apply i1: %s, i2: %s", i1, i2)); 
            return i1 + i2;
        }
    };
}
```

To add to that further the scope of `i1` and `i2` as method arguments to `apply` method are local to the method within the anonymous class which is what your code represents.

#### Further Improvement

If you were to implement adding to `Integer`s(and returning an `Integer`), an alternate and cleaner way would be to have a [`BinaryOperator<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) defined in the scope where you're possibly going to reuse the implementation as :

```
BinaryOperator<Integer> addTwoIntegers = Integer::sum; // (a,b) -> a+b
```

and then use it simply as

```
System.out.println("addTwoIntegers: " + addTwoIntegers.apply(5, 7));
```